# Prove you computed hash^r(input) for some cryptographic hash function

Tags: cryptography, hash, hashing, interactive-proof-systems

What is the most efficient way to prove that a person computed r rounds of some cryptographic hash function (ex. sha256) on an input?. The trivial solution seems to be to show all r hashes, where `value_i = hash(value_(i-1)) /forall i <= r`, but this seems very space inefficient.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48796/351.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Crypto.SE.